# Удобное отображение поля для ввода даты

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день,

В моем приложении на iOS есть view, необходимый для ввода некоторой информации. На нем есть несколько текстбоксов (пока это текстбоксы), в один из которых необходимо ввести дату. Соответственно, я хочу, чтобы по нажатию по этому контроллу открывалась не клавиатура, а отображался UIDatePicker.

Вопроса у меня два:

1. Как мне сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на текстбокс не отображалась клавиатура?
2. Более опытные в организации удобных интерфейсов товарищи, подскажите, пожалуйста, как принято подобные вещи организовывать в юзер-френдли приложениях, чтобы все было интуитивно понятно? Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы весь экран немного затемнялся, а поверх затемнения внизу экрана чтобы был UIDatePicker. Или может быть как-то обыграть это через новый view? Только необходимо учесть, что у меня внизу еще есть панель вкладок, поэтому я не хочу делать слишком нагроможденный интерес.

Буду рад подробным ответам, а так же ссылкам на страницы, где это все подробно объяснялось бы. А то я как-то натыкаюсь на тупые мануалы, как вставить UIDatePicker в свое приложение и все.

Заранее благодарен за полезные ответы

Answer (score 1):

В общем вот:

```
UIDatePicker *myDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
//myDatePicker конфиг пикера...
myTextField.inputView = myDatePicker;
```

Comment: ну и накинуть поверх вьюхи с myTextField вьюху с альфой 0.5, к примеру, для нужного вам затемнения.

+ можно добавить анимацию
++ Матчасть - не надо рассказывать, что нет норм мануалов - плохо искали значит.

Comment: я бы выделил **++ Матчасть**